# How do I reformat .JSON key value pairs to comma-separated values using equals instead of colon?

Tags: javascript, json, string, replace

I have a massive JSON file I want to parse into a table column. However, pure JSON is pretty ugly and doesn't really provide much information.

I'd like to reformat it.

Assuming my input it this JSON:

```
{
    "time": "1492511327.863946000",
    "type": "Vicious",
    "data": {
        "subject": "Danger",
        "ID": "12314",
        "Country": "Russia"
    }
}
```

I wish to output the `data` object in the following format, and populate it in a single column:

`subject=Danger, ID=12314, Country=Russia`

(The real object is much much bigger)

I have seen jQuery options to do it, however I do not have access(and will not) to jQuery.

How do I manipulate a large object in JSON format and convert it to the above output, meaning changing the `:` to `=` and removing quotation marks.

For the latter part, I could regex myself to replacing them.. If they were strings rather than a big object. But that doesn't really work well in this case.

(Example `replace(/['"]+/g, '')`)

Comment: You input JSON as a string or as a file ?

Comment: No it's from a REST endpoint, it comes in being stored in a variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(o)` and store this in an array

```js
var obj ={
    "time": "1492511327.863946000",
    "type": "Vicious",
    "data": {
        "subject": "Danger",
        "ID": "12314",
        "Country": "Russia"
    }
};

let arr = Object.keys(obj.data).map(k=>`${k}=${obj.data[k]}`);

console.log(arr.join(', '));
```